# Python library to compute continuous 1-D wavelet transform

Tags: library, python, signal-processing

I want to compute the wavelet of a signal with different scales and timeshifts.

In Matlab using the [`cwt()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/cwt.html) function (Continuous 1-D wavelet transform) provided in the [Wavelet Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/index.html) I can specify the scale(s) I want as a parameter to cwt(), and it will return all possible timeshifts:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
scales = [1, 2, 3];
wavelet_name = 'db1';
coefs = cwt(x,scales, wavelet_name);

>> coefs =   

   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000
   -0.7071   -0.7071   -0.7071   -0.7071
   -1.1553   -1.1553   -1.1553    1.7371
```

Which library can achieve that in Python with a decent amount of built-in wavelet functions?

Here are my two attempts so far:

1. In [PyWavelets](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/) (Discrete Wavelet Transform in Python), I don't see how I can specify the scale parameter of the wavelet. (probably due to the fact that it is a discrete wavelet transform, not a continuous one)
2. In [`scipy.signal.cwt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cwt.html), I can't find [the list of the built-in wavelet functions that I can pass to scipy.signal.cwt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23730383/395857): I want to have at least the most common wavelet functions such as sym2 and db1. (e.g. see [Matlab's built-in wavelet list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/waveletfamilies.html)).

Comment: Have you already seen [
Where can I see the list of built-in wavelet functions that I can pass to scipy.signal.cwt?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730383/where-can-i-see-the-list-of-built-in-wavelet-functions-that-i-can-pass-to-scipy) on Stackoverflow?

Comment: @sebix Yes actually it's me who added the question/answer there and I had put a link to it in my question here :) I was more looking for well established wavelet libraries, but apparently there is not, so so far the best code is https://github.com/aaren/wavelets/blob/master/wavelets/wavelets.py

Comment: Oh, yes I didn't compare the users :D
Well, AFAIK (and after a quick look in the source) I haven't found a practicable number of built-in wavelets. As my knowledge in this area is nearly zero, I don't want to start an effort now to improve SciPy in this area, maybe later :)

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers from this [DSP question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/18104/1632) by [endolith](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/29/endolith):

> - [Pyscellania](http://web.archive.org/web/20150711022023/http://www.phy.uct.ac.za/courses/python/examples/moreexamples.html#wavelet-analysis-continuous-wavelet-transform) has a [Wavelets](http://web.archive.org/web/20150406051023/http://www.phy.uct.ac.za/courses/python/examples/Wavelets.py) module (now [mirrored at github](https://github.com/emanuele/cwt)) which implements real/complex Morlet, MexicanHat, Paul
>     order 2, Paul order 4, 1st Derivative Of Gaussian, 4th Derivative Of
>     Gaussian, Unnormalised version of continuous Haar transform,
>     Normalised Haar
> - [aaren/wavelets](https://github.com/aaren/wavelets) supports Morlet, Paul, DOG, Ricker
> - Machine Learning PYthon (mlpy) has [`mlpy.wavelet.cwt`](http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/docs/3.1/wavelet.html#continuous-wavelet-transform) that supports Morlet, Paul, and Derivative Of Gaussian wavelets
> - [Dapid/fast-pycwt](https://github.com/Dapid/fast-pycwt) supports Morlet and Ricker
> - ObsPy (seismological observatories) has a [`cwt` module](http://docs.obspy.org/master/tutorial/code_snippets/continuous_wavelet_transform.html) and "for now only 'morlet' is implemented"
> - [pyCWT](https://github.com/Unidata/pyCWT) has Morlet wavelet